# How to install Apache Tomcat 8 on centos 7?

Tags: centos, java, tomcat

I am configuring CentOS 7 system for a Java developer. So firstly I have installed Java using command

```
wget java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
```

after that installed the downloaded package

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
```

and it is successfully installed, and I have checked it using

```
java -version
```

and below is the command reply

```
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.9.0.el7_3-x86_64 u131-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)
```

Please tell me if there is something wrong in the above process.
Now I have to install Apache tomcat 8 but I am studying it over net but that is quite confusing because they are creating groups and something like permissions. Please someone tell me the shortest way because we only want to test the system and will deploy a sample test.war for our testing purpose.

Comment: do you need help on installing tomcat ?

Comment: yes @Ali Golestan

Comment: do you have the tomcat installation files ?

Comment: yes i have downloaded the tomcat7 rpm package using wget @AliGolestan

Comment: please tell me what to do further @AliGolestan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you have installed java on your system, you need to do as i mention here:

`#mv apache-tomcat-7 /opt`

`#useradd tomcat`

`#chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/apache-tomcat-7`

To Install tomcat you need to run the startup.sh

`#cd   /opt/apache-tomcat…`

`#./bin/startup.sh`

now you make tomcat file in `init.d` directory to run tomcat as a service.

`#vim  /etc/init.d/tomcat`

- copy paste the following script in your tomcat file, change directories as it is in your system

> #!/bin/bash
>
> # chkconfig: 234 20 80
>
> # description: Tomcat Server basic start/shutdown script
>
> export TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-7
>   START_TOMCAT=${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/startup.sh
>   STOP_TOMCAT=${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh
>
> export downloadPath=/tmp
>
> export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:PermSize=512m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
>
> start() {
>           echo -n "Starting tomcat: "
>           cd ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin
>           su -p -s /bin/sh tomcat ${START_TOMCAT}
>           echo "done." }
>
> stop() {
>           echo -n "Shutting down tomcat: "
>           cd ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin
>           su -p -s /bin/sh tomcat ${STOP_TOMCAT}
>           sleep 5
>           for pid in `ps -ef | grep  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{print
>   $2}' | xargs`
>           do
>              kill -9 $pid
>           done
>           echo "done." }
>
> case "$1" in
>
> ```
>     start)
>     start
>     ;;
>
>     stop)
>     stop
>     ;;
>
>     restart)
>     stop
>     start
>     ;;
>
>     *)
>     echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
> ```
>
> esac
>
> exit 0

`chmod +x /etc/init.d/tomcat`

`chkconfig --add tomcat`

`su - tomcat`

`service tomcat start`

note that Permsize, xms and xmx sizes are optional and you need to ask your developers for the exact amount.

if you need help on creating users for the web login on tomcat, please ask.

Comment: Actually i have created a directory under /opt named tomcat7, where i have downloaded package so should i install it now using yum install package_name. Sorry i know i am asking very basic question, but i am newbie

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer

To Install tomcat you need to run the startup.sh

go to your apache directory

#cd   /opt/apache-tomcat…

and run 

#./bin/startup.sh

Comment: sorry, but i have used the command =>yum install tomcat-7.0.69-10.el7.noarch.rpm. Now tell me what to do after it.

Comment: Please tell me one thing more whenever we install any package using command yum install package_name(Where the file related to that package are saved in our system) @Ali Golestan

Comment: if your tomcat service is up and running, use your web browser to open the tomcat server address. check to see if your url is working

go to http://ServerIPaddress:8080

Comment: i am running Jenkins on port number 8080

Comment: thanks buddy tomcat has been started, actually i have to change the port number for tomcat from 8080, because i was using jenkins at 8080. thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome, if you need to run tomcat over https i can help you too

Comment: can i reach u via mail

Comment: sure, its aligolestan@gmail.com, if you need the https configue please create a new question for it

Comment: i have started tomcat and its working at =>localhost:9090, but server status link is not working i have made the changes in the file tomcat-users.xml  and these are the changes (<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>). But username and password are not working

Comment: please create a new question